# How to assign a computed value to an observable

Tags: knockout.js

If ToStringStub is a computed, how do I best assign its current value to EmailList ,without any of the computed stuff getting passed on?

```
  self.EmailList = ko.observable(self.ToStringStub());
```

Comment: What do you mean, without any of the computed stuff getting passed on? That should just pass in the value of the computed, nothing else. What are you seeing?

Comment: a simple simulation in jsfiddle could help understand the problem better.

Comment: by executing the computed like that then you will just get the value.  You will only have issues if you don't execute it

Comment: well its weird, after running the above code, self.EmailList bound to the html controls only renders  email@foo.com instead of if its-> eg email@foo.com,email2@foo.com

Comment: hmm even this fails..       var test = self.ToStringStub();
        self.EmailList = ko.observable(test);  and test has the right data, I suspect now my issues lies with the html input not liking the **,** char in -> **email@foo.com,email2@foo.com**. I only get **email@foo.com** rendered

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your need correctly and you want to assign ToStringStub (computed observable) to EmailList than no need to create EmailList observable, just do this:

```
self.EmailList = self.ToStringStub; //no need to use function parenthesis '()'
```

Now the above code will automatically  create the EmailList an observable on ToStringStub and whenever your ToStringStub computed observable changes your EmailList will change as well.

*But your EmailList and ToStringStub always have same values.*

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YPFcG/)

Comment: Actually I want to init self.EmailList (an observable) with the current value of self.ToStringStub(), does that make sense?

Comment: Ok if you just want to initialize your EmailList with current value of your computed observable than your code (mentioned in question) can do the job. But remember after that there will be no dependency between computed observable and your EmailList observable. If you will give me a better understanding of your situation than i can tell better whether it makes any sense.

Comment: yeah thats how I want and understand it to work, the issue is with this:  <input data-bind="value: EmailList" style="width: 100%" /> <input data-bind="value: EmailList" style="width: 100%" />email@foo.com,email2@foo.com. I only get email@foo.com rendered